# J4 API Test Helper missing functions

Tags: joomla-api, restful-api, cms-testing

So I installed `codeception/module-rest` and created an `api.suite.yml` containing:

```
modules:
  enabled:
    - Helper\JoomlaDb
    - Helper\Api
  config:
    Helper\JoomlaDb:
      dsn: "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test"
      user: "root"
      password: "*****"
      prefix: "jos_"
    Helper\Api:
      MicrosoftEdgeInsiders: false 
      # localUser: "www-data"
```

Then i updated the helper class with `php vendor/bin/codecept build`.

When starting one of the default api tests like this:

```
php vendor/bin/codecept run "tests/codeception/api/com_content/" -v --html --fail-fast
```

I get an `[RuntimeException] Call to undefined method ApiTester::amBearerAuthenticated`

The default Joomla 4 tests looks like this:

```
public function testCrudOnArticle(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->amBearerAuthenticated($I->getBearerToken());
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.api+json');
    ...
```

When taking a look in the generated `ApiTesterActions.php` file there is only a `getBearerToken` Function included (besides all DB function).

What needs to be done, so all needed REST functions like `amBearerAuthenticated` get included in the generated `ApiTesterActions.php` file and can be used?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was that using the original api.suite.yml did not work for me. It looks like this:

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - Helper\JoomlaDb
    - Helper\Api
  config:
    Helper\JoomlaDb:
      dsn: "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test"
      user: "root"
      password: "*****"
      prefix: "jos_"
    Helper\Api:
      MicrosoftEdgeInsiders: falseInsiders
      # localUser: "www-data"
env:
   mysql:
     modules:
       enabled:
         - REST:
             url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/index.php/v1
             depends: PhpBrowser
             part: Json
       config:
         Helper\Api:
           url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
           cmsPath: "/"
```

Whats working for me is dropping the env databases and running it like this:

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - Helper\JoomlaDb
    - Helper\Api
    - REST:
        url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/index.php/v1
        depends: PhpBrowser
        part: Json
  config:
    Helper\JoomlaDb:
      dsn: "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test"
      user: "root"
      password: "*****"
      prefix: "jos_"
    Helper\Api:
      MicrosoftEdgeInsiders: falseInsiders
      # localUser: "www-data"
```

That way the REST functions get generated inside the `ApiTesterActions.php`